# How can I get an editor to proofread my JavaScript to tell me when a variable name isn't correct?

Tags: javascript, variables, editor, visual-studio-code, var

I want a way to proofread my JavaScript to make sure I've entered all my variable names correctly. So when I have something like this:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = fooo + 1;
```

I want `fooo` to have a red underline.

Is there a way to do this? I thought Visual Studio Code would be ideal but I'm not too particular about what editor I use.

Comment: Please don't downvote without giving an indication of what's wrong with my question.

Comment: Usually most editors have settings to which how strict the proofreading is. Did you check that?

Comment: try `use strict;`.

Comment: Use a linter. I recommend [ESLint](http://eslint.org/). Use the [`no-undef`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) rule and it will warn you that you are using a variable that has not been defined.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be fixed in Visual Studio Code now that I've installed npm along with Node.js.